# Is there any side effect of not having a physical entity for it to act as parent key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

If I go through google app engine tutorial, I can see their example seem to encourage us to have parent for entities.

Hence, I have the following workable code, for user creation (with email as unique)

```
def parent_key():
    return ndb.Key('parent', 'parent')


class User(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required = True)


class RegisterHandler2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        email = self.request.get('email')
        user_timestamp = int(time.time())
        user = User.get_or_insert(email, parent=parent_key(), email=email, timestamp=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(user_timestamp))
```

Note, `parent` entity physically doesn't exist.

Although the above code runs totally fine, I was wondering any possible problem can occur, if `parent` entity physically doesn't exist?

One of my concern of not having parent, is **eventually consistency**. After write operation, I want my read operation able to fetch the latest written value. I'm using `User.get_or_insert` to write (and read), and `User.get_by_id` to read only.

I want after I execute `User.get_or_insert`, and next request `User.get_by_id` will return latest value. I was wondering, to achieve **strong consistency**, is parent key an important thingy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are no problems as long as you don't actually need this parent entity.
2. You should not make a decision to use parent entities lightly. In fact, using entity groups (parent-child entities) limit the number of entities you can update per second and makes it necessary to know the parent key to retrieve a child entity.

You may run into serious problems. For example, if entity "User" is a child of some parent entity, and then all other entities are children of entities "User", that turns all of your data into one big entity group. Assuming your app is fairly active, you will see datastore operations failures because of this performance limitation.

Note also that a key of an entity gets longer if you have to include a key of a parent entity into it. If you create a chain of entities (e.g. parent -> user -> album -> photo), a key for each "photo" entity will include a key for album, a key for user and a key for parent entity. It becomes a nightmare to manage and requires much more storage space.

Comment: I don't plan to let `user` has any child. In that case, I think it should be ok?

Comment: One of my concern of not having parent, is "eventually consistency". After write operation, I want my read operation able to fetch the latest written value. I'm using `User.get_or_insert` to write (and read), and `User.get_by_id` to read only. I was wondering, to achieve strong consistency, is parent key an important thingy?

Comment: Looking at the [ndb docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id),  `Model.get_by_id` is the same as `Key(cls, id).get()`. Being a fetch-by-key, you will always get strong consistency, regardless of whether you have an ancestor or not.  Off the top of my head I don't know about `Model.get_or_insert` though.  Eventual consistency comes into play when you are doing a query (= index scan).

Comment: Eventual consistency is the price you pay for fast performance. Sometimes eventual consistency is inconvenient, but almost always there is a solution that does not penalize performance.

Comment: note that using parents will seriously affect write rate.

Answer (score 0):

Using a parent key that doesn't correspond to an entity that actually has properties (which is what I think you're referring to as a 'physical entity') is a standard technique.

You can even decide later to add properties to that key.

I've been using this technique for years.

Comment: Please edit your answer to give an example of this technique.  This sounds interesting.  Thanks!